# PPTPD on Centos 64 bit 5.5

Tags: centos

Can I install pptpd on CentOS 5.5 running a 64 bit version? I'm unable to find a package for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following articles should point the way:

[PPTP Server Installation in CentOS 5](http://wingloon.com/2007/11/06/pptp-server-installation-in-centos-5/)
[Installing and Configuring PPTP VPN on RHEL/CentOS 5](https://support.misdivision.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=387) ([alternate link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/48274052/Installing-and-Configuring-PPTP-VPN-on-RHELCentOS-5))

Comment: This only installs pptp client and i'm looking for pptpd i.e. daemon

Comment: OK, so here are some pointers instead.

Comment: FYI @harrymc, your second link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

you can use easily installation by running this script :
  [Install PPTP VPN on CentOS 5 in 1 Minute](http://www.rockia.com/2010/10/easy-installation-of-pptp-vpn-server-on-centos)
or you can install manually by following these step :
  [VPN (PPTP) Server on Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/51237/setting-up-a-vpn-pptp-server-on-debian/)